# d3 show labels only for ticks with data in a bar chart

Tags: d3.js, axis-labels

First, I'm new with D3. :)
I have a stacked bar chart. My y axis is a ordinal scale (state).
In my data, I could have total=0 for some ticks. So, I just want to see the labels when the total > 0 but maintain all the ticks of the data.

```
var data = [{ "state":"A", "total":"10"},
{ "state":"B", "total":"0"},
{ "state":"C", "total":"0"},
{ "state":"D", "total":"20"},
{ "state":"E", "total":"0"},
{ "state":"F", "total":"50"}]
```

I've tried this code, but this remove all the ticks with total = 0. I just want to remove the label of that tick.

```
yAxis.tickValues(dataSet.map( function(d,i) 
    { 
        if (d.total > 0)
            return d.state; 
        else
            if(i % 4 === 0 ) return d.state; 
    })
    .filter(function (d) 
    { return !!d; } ));
```

Thanks,
Filipe

**UPDATE**
Here is the code:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>

    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" class="ocks-org do-not-copy">
    <head>
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />
    </head>
    <body>
    <div id="timeLine"></div>
    <!--style>

    svg {
            font: 10px sans-serif;
        }

    path {
        fill: steelblue;
    }

    .axis path,
    .axis line {
        fill: none;
        stroke: #000;
        shape-rendering: crispEdges;
    }
</style-->
<script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
<script>
var timeline;
var labels;


    var margin = {
        top : 20,
        right : 10,
        bottom : 60,
        left : 80
    },
    width = 500 - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

    var x = d3.scale.linear()
        .rangeRound([0, width]);

        var y = d3.scale.ordinal()
        .rangeBands([height, 0], 0.1);

    var color = d3.scale.ordinal()
        .range(["#1f77b4", "#2ca02c", "#E53524"]);
    //var color = d3.scale.category10()

    var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
        .scale(x)
        .orient("bottom")
        .tickFormat(d3.format(".2s"))
        .ticks(10);

    var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
        .scale(y)
        .orient("left")
        .ticks(5);

    timeline = d3.select("#timeLine").append("svg")
        .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
        .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
        .append("g")
        .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")")

    var dataSet;
    var all_nodes_t;
    var all_updates_t;
    var test;
    var entity = "ALL";

    dataSet = [
    { "Date":"2014-01", "insert":"27", "remove":"17","updates":"427"},
    { "Date":"2014-02", "insert":"27", "remove":"17","updates":"427"},
    { "Date":"2014-03", "insert":"27", "remove":"17","updates":"427"},
    { "Date":"2014-04", "insert":"0", "remove":"0","updates":"0"},
    { "Date":"2014-05", "insert":"27", "remove":"17","updates":"427"},
    ];
        color.domain(d3.keys(dataSet[0]).filter(function (key) {
            return key !== "Date";
        }));

    dataSet.forEach(function (d) {
        var x0 = 0;
        d.ages = color.domain().map(function (name) {
                return {
                    name : name,
                    x0 : x0,
                    x1 : x0 += +d[name]
                };
            });
        d.total = d.ages[d.ages.length - 1].x1;
    });

    //HERE
    yAxis.tickFormat(dataSet.map(function(d) { 
        d.total == 0 ? "" : d.Date; 
    }));

    y.domain(dataSet.map(function (d) {
        return d.Date;
    }));

    x.domain([0, d3.max(dataSet, function (d) {
        return (d.total + 5);
    })]);

    timeline.append("g")
    .attr("class", "x axis")
    .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
    .call(xAxis)
    .append("text")
    .attr("x", 1)
    .attr("dx", "42em")
    .attr("dy", "3em")
    .style("text-anchor", "end")
    .text("Operations");

    timeline.append("g")
    .attr("class", "y axis")
    .call(yAxis);

    var layer = timeline.selectAll(".state")
        .data(dataSet)
        .enter().append("g")
        .attr("class", "rect")
        .attr("transform", function (d) {
            return "translate(0," + y(d.Date) + ")";
        });

    var rect = layer.selectAll("rect")
        .data(function (d) {
            return d.ages;
        })
        .enter().append("rect")
        .attr("class", "rect")
        .attr("width", 0)
        .attr("x", width)
        .attr('y', function (d, i) {
                return y(d.Date);
            })
        .attr("height", y.rangeBand())
        .style("fill", function (d) {
            return color(d.name);
        });

    rect.transition()
    .duration(600)
    .delay(function (d, i) {
        return i * 300;
    })
    .attr("width", function (d) {
        return x(d.x1) - x(d.x0);
    })
    .attr("x", function (d) {
        return x(d.x0);
    });

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You could use the `.tickFormat()` function and return an empty string for the 0 label.

Comment: Hi Lars, thanks for you help. I've tried this yAxis.tickFormat(dataSet.map( function(d,i) 
    {  if (d.total == 0)
            return "";
    })); but I get all labels with "..." text

Comment: It would be something like `.tickFormat(function(d) { d == 0 ? "" : d; })`.

Comment: Sorry Lars, but still not working. My code: 'code' y.domain(dataSet.map(function (d) {
  return d.state;
 }));
 
 x.domain([0, d3.max(dataSet, function (d) {
  return (d.total + 5);
 })]);yAxis.tickFormat(dataSet.map(function(d) { 
  //alert(d.total);
  d.total == 0 ? "" : d.state; 
 })); 'code' I have state as y axis and total as x axis. I only want to show tick labels in y axis when we have total > 0 in x axis. So I add the dataset.map to my function.But I still have "..." text in all labels

Comment: Did you try the code I've posted above?

Comment: Yes Lars, With your code I get empty labels in all ticks. I need to apply the dataSet because is in this variable that we have the total value of each state bar. With your code, the "d" variable is an array with the state and a bunch of zeros. I don't have the total value because that is a x axis value.

Comment: Could you post a complete example please?

Comment: Please, see the entire code sample. In this case I use "Date" instead of "state". So, I need all labels except in "2014-04".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `.tickFormat()` to suppress the labels for those particular values. As the thing you want to check isn't part of the data that's available to the scale, you'll need to find it in your entire data:

```
yAxis.tickFormat(function(d) {
    var val = 0;
    dataSet.forEach(function(item) {
        if(item.Date == d) val = item.total;
    });
    return val == 0 ? "" : d;
});
```

This will suppress the label (return "") if the total is 0 or the value can't be found in the data set. Complete demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/m1ntzdgh/1/).