# D3 scale how to remove the text of the scales and preserve the scale and maintain the max and the minimum

Tags: d3.js, d3plus

Creating the scale:

```
   headers.forEach(function(d) {
                // Coerce values to numbers.
                jsonObj.forEach(function(p) {
                    y[d] = d3.scale.linear().domain(
                            d3.extent(jsonObj, function(p) {
                                return +p[d] || 0;
                            })).range([ h, 0 ]);
                    y[d].brush = d3.svg.brush().y(y[d]).on("brush", brush);
                });
            }); 


g.append("svg:g").attr("class", "axis").each(function(d) {
            d3.select(this).call(axis.scale(y[d]));
```

I would like to preserve the - of the scale.

the Scale is comming [0.0,0.1,0.2,...,1.0]

I want something like this [0,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,1].

It's possible? How can I do this?

Comment: Not sure what you're asking. Are you saying that some of the values in your data are '-' and you want those to appear separately?

Comment: The values in my data are only numbers. But i don't want them appearing in the graph, the text of the numbers, I only want to appear the mark(-) of the number at the scale and the max, minimum number.

Comment: You can use the `axis.tickFormat()` function to do that.

Comment: It's not what I want. I don't want to show the numbers at the middle of the  scale, but I want to maintain the mark of the numbers at the line.

Comment: So you want to show tick marks for everything, but the text labels only for the extreme values? Use `axis.tickFormat()`.

Comment: Ok, but how can I preserve extreme values.

Comment: `.tickFormat()` takes an arbitrary function, the idea is to check whether you're at the extreme values and if so, return the value, else an empty string.

Comment: I got the idea, but I don't know how to check it.

Comment: [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28299330/d3-show-labels-only-for-ticks-with-data-in-a-bar-chart) asks something similar.